# Script wont show hidden element when 'hidden' class is removed

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I have the following function:

```
function submitForCorrection() {
    try {
        $("#uploadSpinner").removeClass("hidden");
        setTimeout(function() {}, 100);
        SubmitForm('BoqReviewForm',
            'boqReviewTable',
            '@Url.Action("PostBoqFlags", "ProjectAuthority")',
            '@Url.Action("GetBoqReview", "ProjectAuthority")',
            function() { showNotification('Correction requested.', 'success'); },
            null,
            'Requesting correction. Please wait',
            false);
    } finally {
        $("#uploadSpinner").addClass("hidden");
    }
}
```

The `SubmitForm` call is rather timeous, hence me wanting to show a 'spinner' while it executes. Yet it's as if my

```
$("#uploadSpinner").removeClass("hidden");
```

line of code is totally ignored.

I know the spinner is in the correct place, because if I put a breakpoint on the `removeClass` line and manually remove the `hidden` class in Chrome dev tools, the spinner shows up exactly where I want it.

I've added the `setTimeout(function() {}, 100);` in the vain hope that removing the `hidden` class may take some time, and I wanted to avoid the `SubmitForm` call executing before the spinner is visible.

Why is my code behaving as if the `removeClass` isn't even there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may appear that the class isn't removed but in reality you are removing the class then adding it back to the element instantly.

In your try catch you have

```
} finally {
  $("#uploadSpinner").addClass("hidden");
}
```

and finally will always run right after your try block has finished.

As stated on MDN:

> finally_statements:
>
> Statements that are executed after the try statement completes. These statements execute regardless of whether an exception was thrown or caught.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

So your code is running the try block which will remove the class but then it is just adding it back instantly in your finally block. This is happening because `setTimeout` and I assume your `SubmitForm` function are both asynchronous.

You will need to return a callback or a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from your `SubmitForm` function so you can then remove the loader after the form has finished submitting.

You should be able to fix this by changing your function to this

```
function submitForCorrection() {        
  $("#uploadSpinner").removeClass("hidden");
  setTimeout(function() {
    SubmitForm('BoqReviewForm',
      'boqReviewTable',
      '@Url.Action("PostBoqFlags", "ProjectAuthority")',
      '@Url.Action("GetBoqReview", "ProjectAuthority")',
      function() {
        showNotification('Correction requested.', 'success');
        $("#uploadSpinner").addClass("hidden");
      },
      null,
      'Requesting correction. Please wait',
      false
    );
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: My point with the `try..finally` is that the `try` block code takes a long time, so the `finally` block shouldn't execute immediately. As things are now, no spinner is shown, but the UI remains unresponsive for some 30 seconds.

Comment: From what you have posted your code looks like it is asynchronous so the try catch won't be taking time to execute, if you add a console log after your `SubmitForm` function it will most likely log before the form has finished submitting

Comment: Nice one on guessing the callback param for `SubmitForm`, and your new code works that far, thanks, but now I'm stuck with the callback not being called.

Answer (score 0):

instead of removing the class, perhaps you should try to change the "display" attribute of the spinner from "none" to "block"

2 ways of doing it is as follow:

$("#uploadSpinner").css("display", "block");

or

$('#uploadSpinner').show();

Comment: I much prefer working with adding or removing classes - it smacks less of inline css, and removing the class works if I do it from dev tools.